# How to use same image for configurable and simple product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload, media

When a image is selected to be displayed for configurable product it is saved `(xyz.png)`  in the media. Now when I select the same image for another simple product It is getting saved in media with different name `( as xyz(1).png )`. Like this way it is takin more amount of space in magento media.I want to use same image for a configurable product and simple product. What should be done for that?

Comment: Is the simple product (or it's image) visible in the frontend somewhere? Because if not, not uploading an image at all might also be a solution.